# Everything in eclipse disappeared

Tags: android, eclipse

I was teaching one of my colleague Android using eclipse and suddenly everything (views) in eclipse disappeared in his PC. Tried everything I know (Reset Perspective, Show View->) to no effect at all. I even tried using a different ADT Bundle directing it to the same workspace, but still no effect. Here's a screenshot of eclipse after the problem occurred. Anybody know why this occurred and how to resolve this issue?

[image: Eclipse Error Screenshot]

Comment: Restarting system, sometime works.

Comment: Forgot to mention that, I did try it. Didn't work

Comment: So, you've tried `Window` --> `Show View` --> `Package Explorer`? Because it looks like you're missing your Package Explorer.

Comment: Yep, I did. I think I'll have to check Jaguar's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your workspace is corrupted. Follow these steps [Recovering a corrupt eclipse workspace](http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/recovering-a-corrupt-eclipse-workspace/)

Comment: His laptop had some Adwares too, so this sounds like the most likely explanation to me. I'll mail that guy telling him to try this (he's not here right now) and I'll post the results. Thanks for the handy link BTW

Comment: It definitely looks like a corrupted workspace. Using a different workspace did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do this,

- Go to your Windows menu
- Select "Show View"
- Click on "Package Explorer"

> [image]

Comment: Tried it (Both Package and Project Explorer). Didn't make a difference

Comment: It shows no change at all. Eclipse stays like shown in the screenshot even when switching between perspectives

Comment: Is that mean it is not opening "package explorer" ?

Comment: Yes. As I said in the OP, I tried Reset Perspective, Show View -> Package Explorer, Show View -> Project Explorer, Restart Eclipse, Restart System but Eclipse stays the way it is (the screenshot)

Comment: Ok it seems very new problem for eclipse. can you paste the lines of "eclipse.ini" file from eclipse folder ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51408/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-thahzan-mohomed)

Answer (score 0):

GO to and click Windows> Reset Perspective

Comment: @adneal Try to Create new Project or import Project

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem today. Fixed by File --> Restart